# How can Android APP give location permissions if location service is disabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location

I am newbie at developing Android apps. My goal is to create a BLE app for my custom device that I have created. In order to create BLE app, I must first learn how to enable location service as BLE needs to have this enabled.

I have read and followed instructions from:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions and
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

**How I prepare my project:**

1. Create brand new Java project Minimum SDK (API 25:Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)
2. Add permissions in AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

3. Add libraries in build.gradle (Module:app) as described in (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#allow-system-manage-request-code)

```
   implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.6"
   implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0"
```

4. Copied the example code provided in https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java on how to request and handle request response to my project.

**Full MainActivity.java code:**

```
package com.example.location_test_v2;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;


import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e("INFO", "PERMISSION ALREADY GRANTED: ");
        }

        else {
            Log.e("INFO", "PERMISSION IS NOT GRANTED: ");
            locationPermissionRequest.launch(new String[] {
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            });
        }

    }
    
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> locationPermissionRequest =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
                        Boolean fineLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false);
                        Boolean coarseLocationGranted = result.getOrDefault(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,false);
                        if (fineLocationGranted != null && fineLocationGranted) {
                            Log.e("INFO", "PRECISE LOCATION GRANTED" );
                        } 
                        else if (coarseLocationGranted != null && coarseLocationGranted) {
                            Log.e("INFO", "APPROXIMATAE LOCATION GRANTED" );
                        } 
                        else {
                            Log.e("INFO", "NO LOCATION GRANTED" );
                        }
                    }
            );
    

}
```

I have paired my physical device to android studio via WiFi and simulating the app on my Samsung Flip 4.

Imagine a scenario where I havent previously installed this app on my phone (lets say it is downloaded for the first time), obviously the location permissions will not be given to this app yet. When the app is opened for the first time, I am prompted to enable location sharing as shown in the image below:

[image]

After choosing the precise or approximate location, everything seems to be fine. I can go to my Settings->Location->App Permissions->Location_test_v2 (my app name) and I can see that the location permissions are given to the app.

**My question:**

My only concern is how is it possible to give location permission to the app if the location service is Off on my phone. How come it does not matter whether I enable or disable the location service?

Answer (score 1):

> How come it does not matter whether I enable or disable the location service?

The location service is what supplies data to `LocationManager`, from GPS and so on.

However, the location *permissions* cover not only that, but other technologies that could be used to determine a device's location, such as scanning for WiFi access points or, reminiscent of your case, detecting BLE beacons.